Unable to resolve "missing-asset-registry-path" from "assets/model/group1-shard2of2.bin"
import { bundleResourceIO } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";

// model path
const modelJson = require("../../assets/model/model.json");
const modelWeights = [
  await require("../../assets/model/group1-shard1of2.bin"),
  await require("../../assets/model/group1-shard2of2.bin"),
];

/**
 * loadModel for Android and IOS
 * loading model via bundleResourceIO and assets
 */
export const modelURI = bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights);


metro.config.js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');
module.exports = (async () => {
    const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig();
    const { assetExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;
    return {
        resolver: {
            // Add bin to assetExts
            assetExts: [...assetExts, 'bin'],
        }
    };
})();

I am trying to import models and use them in @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native but it is not working. Can any one tell what I am doing wrong ?

Hi  Balram,
can you please include the error message in your question so people can properly evaluate your problem?

Android Bundling failed 4274ms node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js (1001 modules)
Unable to resolve "missing-asset-registry-path" from "assets/model/group1-shard1of2.bin"
